# Cкорость выборки с БД и HDD

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, база-данных

Возник небольшой спор с коллегой. Суть задачи: есть товар, у него есть разные картинки, необходимо возвращать эти картинки на клиент. Картинки решили возвращать одним респонсом в виде джейсон обьекта с массивом этих картинок в base64. Вобщем вопрос такой: что лучше по скорости: выбирать эти картинки с базы одним запросом или читать с диска? Могут ли измениться показатели при сильной нагрузке?

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от объема и частоты запроса картинок. Если их немного, а памяти на сервере SQL достаточно, то они будут лежать в кэше SQL Server-а - фактически, в оперативной памяти, и отдаваться достаточно быстро. 
Если же памяти не хватит, то постоянная работа с данными большого объема плохо повлияет на производительность SQL Server'а - в скорости работы с картинками не выиграете, а в производительности остальных запросов проиграете. В таком случае можно использовать FileStream - файлы лежат в файловой системе, но доступ к ним осуществляется, как к объектам SQL.

FileStream еще чем полезен- можно поиграться - сначала положить картинки в базу, посмотреть на производительность, потом выгрузить в ФС и переделать колонку в FileStream - и снова посмотреть. При этом методы работы с объектами не изменятся - все это можно делать, не переписывая код.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, лучше картинки хранить отдельно на диске, а в базе только хранить на них ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Выбирать эти картинки с базы одним запросом (да если мало) или читать с диска (да если много)? Показатели могут измениться в большую сторону. Я бы  на один товар один запрос слал.